# scraping details of embedded interactive map by knowing their CSS class in R

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am going to scrape data from the map in this [link](http://www.farabillboard.com/%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF/?sort=&page=180&search_key=&select_city_master=4&select_city_detail=14&select_position_master=-1&select_position_detail=-1&select_type=-1&select_operate=-1&btnSearch=%D8%AC%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%AC%D9%88#resulttop)
first I scraped all lat-long of all of the markers in the map, but I cant catch other information of markers. In the inspection of this webpage I find the class of needed data is "infodetail" like this picture:

[image]

so, I used `rvest` to extract the data as below:

`webhtml <- read_html(webpage)
webnod <- html_nodes(webhtml, 'div.infodetail')`

but I get an empty list even when trying `infodetail` or `.infodetail`.

how can I find exact class or argument for `html_nodes`? does this class extract information from all markers?

Comment: Having maps and charts like this in javascript with popups, I'd say there's a very very good chance that there's only one popup element in the document (looks like `div.infodetail` is it) whose child element gets filled with formatted text each time you hover or click on a marker. So this data wouldn't be hard-coded in the page for all the values, but filled in dynamically.

Comment: To verify that since you have `div.infodetail` highlighted in your devtools, click on different markers and see the text in its `<p>` elements change. Or see if you can find more than that one `<div>` with the class `infodetail`

Comment: @camille : I cant do that because only one popup can be activated.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm saying, there's only one popup element in the document. Information gets placed inside it when you click each marker. Click different markers and verify that the text in the popup element is changing, by looking at the Inspector panel of your devtools

Comment: @camille : so, I can not scrape these data automatically! can I?

Comment: Not from the popup, I don't think so. I wanted you to see how the popup works that makes it not scrapeable on its own. The form element `#filterBoardForm` has a `GET` method to get data from a database when you click the submit button. You might be able to use something like RSelenium to programmatically submit form options and scrape the data that shows up in the table below, then page through the results

Answer (score 0):

You should send the request to a different URL which fetches the information embedded in the node.

[image]

[image]

For example,  you should send get request to this URL: http://www.farabillboard.com/board/GetBoardMapInfo/boardid/6299
And you can get the information you need.

Comment: thank you very much. but it seems that I should send a request for all of the pins in the map. for this purpose eat least I should know the four digits at the end of URL for all of the pins. is there any way to automate this process?

Comment: I can't read the language. But have you tried the dashboards below? Maybe they are related.

Comment: yes, they are related. although they have some defects which need a little manipulation. my goal was to know more about scraping interactive maps. however, thank you very much for your valuable guidance.

Comment: To scrape from interactive parts is not that easy. It's better to find an alternative. Hope your project going well.