# Use R to Scrape information from interacitve embedded popups in dynamic website

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I'm trying to scraping the information of those small yellow car from a dynamic website: [Trunk road gritter tracker](https://www.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=2de764a9303848ffb9a4cac0bd0b1aab)

It is a dynamic website that contains many yellow cars,each car has its own information like 'Vehicle', 'Age(range)', 'source date' .etc. And when you click on the car, the information will pop up.

However, I can only click to open the information bar for a single car once at a time, which means I can only get one specific popup data at a time, and correspondingly, the scraping result is only for that specific car. How can I scrape for the information bar for all cars?

In the initial state of the web page, the car has not been clicked, so my idea is to use the **remdr$findelement()** function to navigate the car, and then use **clickElement()** to simulate clicking. After clicking, a pop-up window will appear, and then use **html_ Nodes()** and **html_text()** function to scrape the information. After scraping, simulate clicking the pop-up close button. So far, the scraping of one car is completed, and then repeat this process to achieve scraping of all car information.

[image]
I used Rselenium and rvest, and here is my code:

```
remDr = remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr="localhost",port=4444L,browserName="chrome")
    remDr$open(silent = T)
    url = "https://www.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=2de764a9303848ffb9a4cac0bd0b1aab"
    remDr$navigate(url)
    
    image_button = remDr$findElement('xpath', value = "//*[@id='TSWT_VehiclesAndTrail_2020_1393_layer']/*[name()='image']")
    image_button$clickElement()
    
    webpage <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
    data <- webpage %>% html_nodes(".attrValue") %>% html_text()
    data
```

However, there are some problems. I don't know how to use **findElement()** to navigate to the cars when many cars are in the same page. The strcutre for the image of the cars is shown below. Although each image has its own specific xPath, it is in a nested strcutre and I cannot findelement successfully by directly search for that image xpath. According to these two answers:[Finding SVG Elements using RSelenium and XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57866017/finding-svg-elements-using-rselenium-and-xpath)
 and [trigger all pop-ups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466887/scraping-details-of-embedded-interactive-map-by-knowing-their-css-class-in-r), instead I use `remDr$findElement('xpath', value = "//*[@id='TSWT_VehiclesAndTrail_2020_1393_layer']/*[name()='image']")` But this works only when I enlarge the page so that there is only one car on the screen, I can get the information successfully, when more than one cars are in the screen, nothing will be return. And I tried  `remDr$findElement()[[1]]` bu it still doesn't work.

```
<svg>
    <g id=xxx>
        <image></image>
        <image></image>
        <image></image>
            .
            .
            .
    </g>
</svg>
```

How can I get all the different information from different popups at once? Is my idea feasible, or is there any other simpler way?